# Does Solaris/Illumos have a daemon for at jobs, or manage internally?

Tags: solaris, at, illumos, job-scheduler

I scheduled a test `at` job and reviewed it with `atq`, but I do not see an `atd` daemon which will carry them out.

Is this managed within the Solaris / Illumos kernal? If not, which daemon manages `at` jobs?

I am actually surprised not to find `atd`, because there is a daemon for `cron` already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the man page of `cron` in Solaris 10:

> NAME
>
> cron - clock daemon
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> /usr/sbin/cron
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> cron starts a process that executes  commands  at  specified dates and
>   times.
>
> You can specify regularly scheduled commands to cron according  to
>   instructions found in crontab files in the directory
>   /var/spool/cron/crontabs. Users can submit their own crontab file 
>   using the crontab(1) command. Commands which are to be executed only
>   once can be submitted using the **at(1)** command.
>
> cron only examines crontab or **at** command  files  during  its own 
>   process initialization phase and when the crontab or **at** command is
>   run. This reduces the overhead  of  checking  for new or changed files
>   at regularly scheduled intervals.
>
> As cron never exits, it should be executed only  once.  This is  done 
>   routinely  by  way of the svc:/system/cron:default service. The file
>   /etc/cron.d/FIFO file is used  as  a  lock file  to  prevent the
>   execution of more than one instance of cron.
>
> cron captures the output of  the  job's  stdout  and  stderr streams, 
>   and,  if  it is not empty, mails the output to the user. If the job
>   does not produce output, no mail is sent to the user. An exception is
>   if the job is an **at(1)** job and the
>   -m option was specified when the job was submitted.
>
> cron and **at** jobs are not executed if your account is locked. Jobs  and
>   processses  execute.  The  shadow(4) file defines which accounts are
>   not locked and will have their  jobs  and processes executed.

So there is no `atd` in Solaris, one-time jobs are handled by the `cron` daemon as well.

Comment: This is a very common configuration on non-systemd linux and bsd as well.

Comment: Aha! There it is! .. I'm glad there is a visible daemon for it - as there is for most things.

Comment: BTW. Interestingly Solaris seems to be moving away from `cron` although it will possibly continue to exist in Solaris for the next 20 years or so: In Solaris 11.3 you can now use SMF for periodic jobs (of course you can also still use `cron`) and I suspect it is only a matter of time before one-time jobs can be handled by SMF as well.